# Calculate $Y$ based on new$(X,Y)$ coordinates (from horizontally and vertically translated $x,y$)

Tags: coordinate-systems

For this quadratic function, I need to translate the $(x,y)$ coordinate axes horizontally and vertically, so that the new origin of the coordinate system is located at the point with old coordinates $(2,3)$.

The new $(X,Y)$ coordinates are therefore related to the old $(x,y)$ -system by the equations:

***Question -1***

Since the new coordinates is 2 and 3 for x and y respectively, I substract them from x and y. Even though it is correct when I enter into the system, I don't fully understand why I need to substract, why not addition.

**If you could guide me for further reading or explanation, that would be great.**

$X = x -2 $

$Y = y -3 $

$ y = 2x^2−3x+1$

I need to substitute these $X = x -2, Y = y -3$, into the formula $y = 2x^2−3x+1$, in order to express Y as a function of X.

Below is the work.
$y = ax^2 + bx + c
       = a(x + b/2a)^2 + (c-b^2/4a)$

$y = 2x^2−3x+1
\
       = 2( x - 3/4)^2 + (1-9/8)
\
       = 2( x - 3/4)^2 -1/8
\
   y + 1/8 = 2( x - 3/4)^2$

Let $Y=  y + 1/8$

Let $X=  x - 3/4$

Therefore $Y=2X^2$

**Question -2**

My calculation for Y is as below. However, when I enter this answer, I still get incorrect response. I have checked it many times, but still couldn't spot the mistake. Is my method incorrect?

$y -3 = 2(x-2)^2 - 3(x-2)+ 1$

$y = 2(x^2 -4x + 4) - 3x -6 + 1 + 3$

$y = 2x^2 -8x + 8 -3x -2$

$y = 2x^2 -11x + 6$

Comment: @Jneven Thanks for adding $ to X and Y. I learnt new way of marking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

I do not know if i can satisfy your first question. Simply put the new center coordinates in your equation

$$ X= x-2 = 2-2 = 0, $$
$$ Y= y-3 = 3-3 = 0. $$

You see that $X$ an $Y$ are zero at the new center $x=2$ and $y=3$.

Or vice versa put the old center coordinates in the new system

$$ -2= x-2, $$
$$ -3= y-3, $$

resulting in

$$ x=-2+2=0, $$
$$ y=-3+3=0. $$

You see that $x$ an $y$ are zero at old center for $X=-2$ and $Y=-3$.

**Question 2:**

In the second line there is a typo

$$ y= 2 (x^2 -4 x + 4) - 3x  + 6 + 1 + 3 .$$

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes, -6  is where I made a mistake!!! I didn't spot it yesterday. Thanks for explaining the coordinates question 1.